# Does Chrome developer tools somewhere show all its warnings in one list?

Tags: css, google-chrome-devtools

Chrome developer tools is showing me an `Invalid property value` warning triangle against one of my CSS settings.

[image]

This is crucial to working out why the page layout has gone to pieces. But I only found it by accident.

Thing is, there may be more badness like this lurking in the page. Is there somewhere where Chrome shows all these warnings in a list?

Clicking on the `Errors`, the `Warnings` and the `triangle` (with count=11) in the footer all do nothing.

[image]

Comment: Click `All`. Is that what you're after?

Comment: MelanciaUK is right. You also want to click All or Warnings

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you Inspect Element, go to Console at the top. Then on the bottom of the window click the icon that looks like a flashlight on the left of "All" and "Errors". Here you'll see a list pop up listing JavaScript, Network, Logging, CSS, Other. Some may or may not have check marks next to them. Check CSS if it isn't checked.

Hope it helps.

Source: http://benfrain.com/test-your-sass-or-css-with-the-chrome-developer-tools/

Comment: It's not a flashlight; it's a funnel.

Comment: CSS is not in the list (Chromium 55), nor are CSS warning shown when "All" is selected.

Comment: CSS warnings were removed from Console in [issue 309982](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=309982)